# Convert a list of lists of tuples to a tuple of lists of lists in python

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

I am writing a program for NER tagging with nltk and Mallet. I have to convert between two formats of input data that I cannot change.

The data basically contains words with their associated tags for supervised learning, but there's a subdivision of the data into sentences, hence the list of lists.

The first format is

```
tuple(list(list(word)),list(list(tag)))
```

and the second format is

```
list(list(tuple(word,tag))
```

Currently I am converting it like this (format 2 => format 1):

```
([[tup[0] for tup in sent] for sent in train_set],
 [[tup[1] for tup in sent] for sent in train_set])
```

Sample data:

```
 [[('Steve','PERSON'),('runs','NONE'),('Apple','ORGANIZATION')],[('Today','NONE'),('is','NONE'),('June','DATETIME'),('27th','DATETIME')]]
```

and expected output:

```
 ([['Steve', 'runs', 'Apple' ],['Today','is','June','27th']],
  [['PERSON','NONE','ORGANIZATION'],['NONE','NONE','DATETIME','DATETIME']])
```

I perform conversion in both directions

EDIT: I don't necessarily want it to be shorter - please just suggest a better (and more readable) way  of doing it in python 2.7 (with code sample).

Comment: Provide sample data and expected output.

Comment: Less characters **does not** mean better. With your solution you are performing the same loop twice. If you would write it in a classical `for ... in ...` fashion it would be longer, but 1) more efficient (one loop) and 2) easier to read (well, at least for me).

Comment: explain the downvote, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting `list(list(tuple(word,tag))` to `tuple(list(list(word)),list(list(tag)))` is easy:

```
def convert(data_structure):
     sentences, tags = data_structure
     container = []
     for i in xrange(len(sentences)):
         container.append(zip(sentences[i], tags[i]))

     return container
```

The code for converting into the other direction is a bit longer but not very complicated if you simply use nested `for` loops:

```
def convert(data_structure):
    sentences = []
    tags = []

    for sentence in data_structure:
        sentence_words = []
        sentence_tags = []

        for word, tag in sentence:
            sentence_words.append(word)
            sentence_tags.append(tag)

        sentences.append(sentence_words)
        tags.append(sentence_tags)

    return (sentences, tags)
```

Perhaps the code can be shortened more but the general principle should be clear, hopefully.

Comment: thanks. the code is quite readable. however, I don't understand the part with `container` in the second snippet. couldn't it just be `return (sentences,tags)` ?

Comment: Indeed, the variable `container` is obsolete here. I wrote this code very quickly. I'm glad that my answer has helped you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the inner tuples to iterators(using `iter`) and then call `next` on them in a nested list comprehension:

```
lis = [[('Steve','PERSON'),('runs','NONE'),('Apple','ORGANIZATION')],
       [('Today','NONE'),('is','NONE'),('June','DATETIME'),('27th','DATETIME')]]

it = [[iter(y) for y in x] for x in lis]
n = len(lis[0][0])  #Number of iterations required.
print [[[next(x) for x in i] for i in it] for _ in range(n)]
```

**Output:**

```
[[['Steve', 'runs', 'Apple'], ['Today', 'is', 'June', '27th']],
 [['PERSON', 'NONE', 'ORGANIZATION'], ['NONE', 'NONE', 'DATETIME', 'DATETIME']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct solution will be this one:

```
>>> data = [[('Steve','PERSON'),('runs','NONE'),('Apple','ORGANIZATION')],[('Today','NONE'),('is','NONE'),('June','DATETIME'),('27th','DATETIME')]]
>>> tuple([ map(list, (zip(*x))) for x in data ])
([['Steve', 'runs', 'Apple'], ['PERSON', 'NONE', 'ORGANIZATION']], [['Today', 'is', 'June', '27th'], ['NONE', 'NONE', 'DATETIME', 'DATETIME']])
```

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't yield the expected result. please re-check my question

Comment: Yes, true. let me check again.